# How to modify a file from the process context of iexplore.exe?

Tags: debuggers

When I use Process Monitor to check `iexplore.exe`, I see some operations like lock/read/write from `iexplore.exe` to a specific file.

How can I do a modification to this specific file as `iexplore.exe`?

In short: how can I make a running Internet Explorer instance modify a file?

Comment: Please refrain from using all-caps. Thanks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L yes this is wanted question thanks

Comment: you want iexplore.exe to modify the specific file with your own data?

Comment: @ph0sec yes iexplore or any other process ...

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways is to load your code into that process (*iexplore.exe*) and hook the file creation/writing APIs. This will give you the way to alter that process IO.

But why would you do that? This will look like pretty malicious activity.

Are you sure, there is no way to solve your problem without doing what you've asked?

**Update** - I hope what you are saying is true.

- [Code injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces) - will explain the injection with several examples:

> Introduction
>   Windows Hooks
>   The CreateRemoteThread & LoadLibrary Technique
>     -- Interprocess Communications
>
> The CreateRemoteThread & WriteProcessMemory Technique
>     -- How to Subclass a Remote Control With this Technique
>      When to Use this Technique

- [API Hooking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks)

Also, do some searching on the subject of hooking, there are a lot info on the Net.

Comment: Given past questions, I would reckon that this is an attempt at circumventing the DRM scheme somehow?!

Comment: @ph0sec yes i know that is the way but how to load my code inside iexplore.exe on the load and executer it, AND NO THERE IS NO MALICIOUS JUST WANT TO DO IT

Answer (score 3):

Create a DLL with your code in it.

You can then write an EXE to perform the following steps:

1. Use `CreateProcess()` or `OpenProcess()` on Internet Explorer to get a handle to the Internet Explorer process.
2. Call `VirtualAllocEx()` to allocate memory in the IE process using the handle from Step 1.
3. Call `WriteProcessMemory()` to write the file path of your DLL into the memory allocated in Step 2.
4. Call `CreateRemoteThread()` to call `LoadLibrary()` from IE's process to load the DLL whose path you just wrote into IE's memory in Step 3.

These steps are discussed in greater detail at http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/

Comment: thanks for the reply ! it sounds the best way , just one think how to make static constructor since the dll is called a function starts ?